# How to fix Unity MacOS application that only hangs/freezes when running in "Application" folder

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, httpwebrequest, freeze, coroutine

I've built a Unity MacOS application that runs fine in the debugger, and fine when run from the build directory, but when the *.app file is copied over to the "Applications" folder, it hangs for 30 seconds when performing an async action. Does anyone know why / how to fix it?

My code essentially looks like this:

```
private void Start()
{
  StartCoroutine(StartLate());
}

IEnumerator StartLate()
{
  yield return null;

  using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get("<my url>"))
  {
    UnityWebRequestAsyncOperation async = www.SendWebRequest();

    int i=0;
    while (!async.isDone)
    {
      Debug.Log(i++);
      yield return null;
    }
    Debug.Log("Complete");

    // Actually act on the result...

  }
}
```

When running in the Unity debugger, or a standalone build in the build directory, then the output looks like:

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9..... 100 101 Complete`

If I copy the application over to the "Application" directory and then run it however then the output is:

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9..... 100 101` <30 second hang> `Complete`

Note that this is a proper "hang" - the entire application freezes, and the mouse cursor changes to the MacOS hung animation.

Does anyone know what causes this and/or how to fix and/or workaround it?

---

EDIT: For clarification there doesn't seem to be anything special about the async pattern.  I also get the same pause-only-when-run-from-in-the-Application-directory behaviour when the substantive section of the code looks like:

```
www.SendWebRequest();
while (!www.isDone)
  yield return null;
```

or

```
yield return www.SendWebRequest();
```

Comment: why did you async? thats not how its demonstrated in use..

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify - the async pattern isn't important here, I only used it to help demonstrate exactly where the hang/freeze happens.  The same behaviour occurs when using other patterns.

Comment: I wouldnt start it with "StartCoroutine(StartLate());" - Ive always started it as StartCoroutine(StartLate) .. .. cant say ive had this sort of thing hang my app